# Selecting next N rows from table with left join

Tags: sql, join, fetch

I'm writing a program that selects a list of companies from a database and returns them on an API. The results are paged in increments of 25. The query itself selects all data from my companies table, then does a left join on a linking table to get a list of reps associated with that company. The problem is, it only returns 25 rows, whereas the left join could cause a lot more rows to be necessary for selecting 25 companies. How can I modify my query to select the first 25 companies, instead of first 25 rows.

```
SELECT 
[dbo].[ClientAccounts].*,
[dbo].[AccountLink].[RepId]
 FROM [dbo].[ClientAccounts]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AccountLink] ON [dbo].[AccountLink].[AccountID] = [dbo].[ClientAccounts].[ID]
WHERE [dbo].[ClientAccounts].[ClientID] = 10
ORDER BY [dbo].[ClientAccounts].[ID] ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to gather your 25 rows first and join them in a second step.

You can try something like this:

```
WITH accounts AS (
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ClientAccounts]
    ORDER BY [dbo].[ClientAccounts].[ID] ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT
    accounts.*,
    [dbo].[AccountLink].[RepId]
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AccountLink] ON [dbo].[AccountLink].[AccountID] = 
[dbo].[ClientAccounts].[ID]
```

Keep in mind, that CTE (common table expressions) are supported by Microsoft since MS SQL Server 2008.